# is there any Concurrent LinkedHashSet in JDK6.0 or other libraries?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

my code throw follow exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:761)
        at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:696)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
        at java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(LinkedHashSet.java:152)
        ...
```

I want a `ConcurrentLinkedHashSet` to fix it,

but I only found `ConcurrentSkipListSet` in `java.util.concurrent`,this is `TreeSet`, not `LinkedHashSet`

any easies way to get `ConcurrentLinkedHashSet` in JDK6.0?

thanks for help :)

Comment: Are you trying to add or remove elements while looping over said linkedhashset? The solution might not be using a concurrent set, but rather, using an iterator to perform modifications mid-loop

Comment: I got a `ConcurrentLinkedHashSet` here:http://artemis.ms.mff.cuni.cz/viewvc/pogamut/trunk/project/Core/src/cz/cuni/amis/utils/sets/?pathrev=2475 :)

Comment: I wasn't saying that you can't get a ConcurrentLinkedHashSet, but that your problem may be coming from modifying your linkedhashset in a loop, and if that was the case, using an iterator from the linkedhashset would be a far more appropriate solution. You should not need a concurrent linked hash set unless there is threading involved in your program.

Comment: @Zach L very thanks for help, you mean I will change `Set rs=new LinkedHashSet(list)` to 
`Set rs=new LinkedHashSet();
for (Iterator ir = list.iterator(); ir.hasNext();) {
 rs.add(ir.next());
}`

right? thanks :)

Comment: if you post a [SSCCEE](http://sscce.org/), i.e. a short, self-contained, compilable example, of where you are getting this error, we'll be able to offer you better help. From your small example, neither should throw a ConcurrentModificationException, ostensibly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A ConcurrentModificationException has nothing to do with concurrency in the form you're thinking of. This just means that while iterating over the Collection, someone (probably your own code - that happens often enough ;) ) is changing it, i.e. adding/removing some values.

Make sure you're using the Iterator to remove values from the collection and not the collection itself.

Edit: If really another thread is accessing the Collection at the same time, the weak synchronization you get from the standard library is useless anyhow, since you've got to block the Collection for the whole duration of the operation not just for one add/remove! I.e. something like

```
synchronize(collection) {
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Note that this changes the contract for the collection and (depending what components are using the collection and how) it can be tricky to change it (get all clients to comply). Rhetorical question: When you are iterating a collection provided to you by a different component/framework do you think if the implementation is safe for concurrent iteration and if there can be modifications done to it in parallel? Chances are authors of other components have no thought of that too ...

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a synchronized collection with `Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);`. However, trying to alter the map while you're iterating (which I'm assuming is the cause of your error) will still be a problem.

From the docs for synchronizedMap:

Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) map backed by the specified map. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing map is accomplished through the returned map.

> It is imperative that the user
>   manually synchronize on the returned
>   map when iterating over any of its
>   collection views ... Failure to follow
>   this advice may result in
>   non-deterministic behavior.

This is because

- normally a concurrent collection is really guaranteeing atomic get/put but is not locking the entire collection during iteration, which would be too slow. There's no concurrency guarantee over iteration, which is actually many operations against the map.
- it's not really concurrency if you're altering during iteration, as it's impossible to determine correct behavior - for example,  how do you reconcile your iterator returning hasNext == true with deleting a (possibly the next value) from the collection?

Answer (score 2):

There is ConcurrentLinkedHashMap - https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/

You can create Set out of it with java.util.Collections.newSetFromMap(map)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You could implement your own, wrapping a ConcurrentHashMap and a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, but this wouldn't allow you to remove values easily (removal would be O(N), since you'd have to iterate through everything in the queue) ...

What are you using the LinkedHashSet for though? Might be able to suggest alternatives...